# How to automatically configure the keyboard, in order to get "¿?" by just pressing "?"

Tags: keyboard-layout

In Spanish there is no question mark `?` alone, but it needs to be opened by `¿`. Is there a way to configure the keyboard, in order to automatically produce the pair `¿?` by just pressing one key (say `?`)

Answer (score 2):

Sadly no. At least there isn't a way to make it work in all text editors. There are some that will "Autocorrect" the wrong ? at the start but no one actually adds both when you press one.

I would recommend you to use a spanish layout instead, or if you are stuck with the english one, at least use it with AltGr dead keys, that has a key combination to add the ¿:

[image]

In the image is chopped off, but besides Shift R, when you press <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> it sends ¿.